# How to add styles programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html in the following format

```
<li class="top"><a href="#nogo2" id="myClass" class="top_link"><span class="down">Test Text</span></a>
```

The classes top and top_link are defined in the css 
Now I want to add all these properties programmatically using javascript

what I have tried ?

```
function createdropMenu() {
    var STList = widget.createElement('li',{
        'id': 'sTools',
        'class': 'SList'});

    STList.addClassName('top');
    STList.addClassName('top_link');             
}
```

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly . How do I add `<span class="down">Test Text</span>` programmatically ?

Comment: what is that 'widget' object you are referencing?

Comment: What properties? You want to add inline-styles? Or you mean you want to add the styles to the style sheet? I'm confused by what you're asking.

Comment: @Tudmotu its a wrapper over document

Comment: Well I can't guess, you have to be explicit about what you're asking. Kind of what?

Comment: @DeeMac ok . I dont intend to include the css styles here . Just the styles that were used while creating a static ul / li

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar what is `addClassName()`?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar - I'm non the wiser, what exactly do you want to do??

Comment: I create a li with var myV = createElement('li', { 'class' : 'ABC' ,'id':'temp'
});  Now I want to add the styles or properties that u can see in the html I refered like spanclass or the "top" class or the "top_link" class

Comment: I'm still confused mate, maybe I'm missing the point altogether. In your original post you ask `"How do I add <span class="down">Test Text</span> programmatically?"` but now it seems like you're asking about adding classes to elements. I don't understand at all what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DeeMac <span class="down">Test Text</span>  is an example . The classes top,top_link,down are defined in the css like
 li.top {display:block; float:left;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your question:

> How do I add `<span class="down">Test Text</span>` programmatically ?

You can use the [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) method attached to your `STList` node:

```
var span = widget.createElement('span', { 'class': 'down' });
STList.appendChild(span);
```

Presumably though you'd also want to add the `a` element, and add the `span` element to that instead:

```
var a = widget.creatElement('a', {
            href: '#nogo2',
            id: 'myClass',
            'class': 'top_link'
        });

a.appendChild(span);
STList.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: What about top and top_link ? same way ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar you can simply `STList.className += ' top top_link';`

Comment: So summing up ur suggestions it should be equivalent to <li class="top"><a href="#nogo2" id="myClass" class="top_link"><span class="down">Test Text</span></a>  ?

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar if you want the `top_link` class to be applied to the `a` element, you'd specifying that in the above `'class'` property when creating the element: `'class': 'top_link'`. To get the `top` class on your `STList` element you'd use `STList.className += ' top';`. I've edited my answer slightly to make the change to the `a` element's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = down;

Insert your span in to your dom by,
/*someelement*/.appendChild(span);
```

Hope that helps. :)